# background process in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cllocation

I want to do local push Notification (giving alert) when the user
comes in particular locations(in range).is it possible to do it? any example and tutorial please?

Answer (score 1):

I hope it would help : http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html

and you can search for pushmebaby for testing push notification in iPhone.

Comment: please see my question . i asked for location.The url you provided is for scheduling time.when we reach particular location, is it possible to give alert in background?

Comment: yes, when you reach a location, your app get the location and trigger the notification by your iphone (which i mention local-push-notification).